# $A$ and $B$ are $3 X 3$ real matrices such that $rank (AB) = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are $3 X 3$ real matrices such that $rank (AB) = 1$ ,then rank (BA) _______?

since $rank (AB) =1

|AB|=|A||B|=0$

It implies, atleast |A|=0 or |B|=0

Hence, $rank (BA)$ cannot be 3.

and ,also there is a result

$rank (A) + rank (B) -3\leq rank(AB)\leq min(rank (A) , rank (B) )$
$rank (A) + rank (B) -3\leq rank(BA)\leq min(rank (A) , rank (B) )$
from above it gives rank (BA) is 1.

Comment: What is your question? :)

Comment: cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268153/a-and-b-are-3-times-3-real-matrices-such-that-operatornamerankab-1?rq=1